# Javamail API: Returning star characters in mail body if text in is bold or italic or underlined etc for text/plain content type

Tags: google-app-engine, email, jakarta-mail

As part of mail receiving and preserving process, we are using javamail api for parsing mails.
We are fetching only text/plain content type. If the mail contains bold or italic texts then content in text/plain returning * characters in place of html tags.

For eg:
Sent mail: Hi **John**, *How* are you!
Received mail(text/plain): Hi *John*, *How* are you! instead of Hi John, How are you!.

Take a look at the following screenshots.
What text I have sent:
[image: What text I have sent]
What I have received in app engine.
[image]

Please help me to get plain content without * characters.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't expect to get html tags if you're only looking at the plain text parts of the message.  If you want to see the html tags, look for the text/html parts.  You probably want to learn about multipart/alternative messages as well.

As a convention, '*' characters are often used in plain text email to emphasize words, similar to bold in rich or html text.

Comment: Hey Bill, Thanks for the reply.I'm expecting plain content only without * characters. I dont know why I'm getting * characters?.

Comment: You're getting them either because that's what the sender entered, or because the sender entered html text with bold and the sending mailer converted that to plain text with stars to represent the bold text.

Comment: That might be correct Bill. Sender might converting bold tags to stars to represent bold text.